# Cannot find night train Rome-Siracusa after June 11 (2016)

Tags: trains, public-transport, italy, sicily, trenitalia

I want to book a night train from Rome to Sicily for this June (2016).

Suspiciously, the official website http://www.trenitalia.com/ lists night trains to sicily, e.g. Roma-Siracusa, only up to the 11th of June. After that date there are no such trains.

Also I couldn't find any relating information on the web.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Very related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66898/32134

Comment: @mts In fact, looks so related as to be a duplicate to me. Any reason it shouldn't be?

Comment: @CMaster before marking dupe I'd like to check if one gets the same error code for both problems while trying to book as in the other Q or if the train does not even show up.

Comment: The underlying problem maybe is the same. But the linked question is much broader than mine which may get a straight answer of general value.

Comment: @mts ... the trains do not show up.

Comment: So the Qs are different but the problem is likely the same. In your case the train connection does not even show while in the other Q it does show and you can't book it.

Comment: @Jan I see you are Germany-based, get a travel agent to figure this out, DB might be able or call a specialized agency (quick google or seat61 will find). Better than waiting for trenitalia or an answer here. Please post if you find any news. +1 on your Q from me.

Comment: @mts - I will, definitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://help.loco2.com/article/316-how-far-in-advance-can-i-book#horizon) lists the advanced booking restrictions for various train operators in Europe including those in Italy.

Booking Horizon:

> Italy High-speed, medium & long-distance 4 months Regionale 2 months
>   (7 days for paperless tickets)

Edit: I realise that doesn't explain bookings after June 11, but [this page](http://help.loco2.com/article/496-summer-timetable-change) should explain issues due to the Summer timetable changes.

Comment: The change to the summer schedule seems to be the issue. Thanks for pointing this out.